# Access HTML data in JSP

Tags: jsp

Say I have a div like this in my jsp page

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

Now, I want to access the div data in my JSP,

```
<%String a = request.getParameter("editor");
System.out.println(a);
request.setAttribute("mytxt1", a);%>
```

but this is always being displayed as null.

What si the correct way to access div data in JSP??

Comment: `<div>` has no name attribute which is required by `request.getParameter("paramName")` (`id` attributes are refernced by a client script like JavaScript). This cannot be done.

Comment: @Code Why do you want this to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.getParameter()` will only get the values from `input`, `select`, and `textarea` which have a `name` attribute and are inside a `form`, and it will only get them after the form has been submitted.

If you want to send a value from a `div` with a certain id to a JSP/Servlet, you will have to either use Ajax to do it, or you can put the div in a form and give it an input like below:

```
<form action='whatever.jsp' method='post'>
   <div id="editor">Here is the value 
        <input type='hidden' name='editor' value='Here is the value' />
   </div>
   <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Now when that form is submitted, the hidden input with name 'editor' will be sent.  Obviously doing that, you have to have the value twice.  It would make more sense to use Ajax.